# How to populate select dropdown elements from API data?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm trying to create a dynamic **Dropdown select**. I'm importing the data from fetched **API** successfully from another component. I want to populate **select option** by **category**  from the **fetched data**, which is an **array** of a single string either 'women', 'men' or 'kids' . What I want,  is to have initially all data listed,  to have 3 **options** for **category** strings and list only matching **products** according to the **onChange** event.
Now when I click to the **select** the whole app renders and can't see the bug.
Any help will be appreciated

Here is how API data looks like:

```
[
  {
    categories: [
      'women'
    ],
    variants: [
      'white',
      'black',
      'green'
    ],
    sizes: [
      38,
      39,
      40
    ],
    _id: '5f8edf08880a821cb8757d8a',
    name: 'Nike Air',
    description: 'Tennis court levitating sneaker',
    img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/PGTO_A0eLt4',
    price: 100,
    __v: 1
  }
]
```

**Category** component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Categories = ({ categories }: any) => {
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('')

    console.log('category', category)
    return (
      <>
        <select 
          value={category}
          onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
         >
          <option value="">Select</option>
          {categories && categories.map((option: any) => (
           <option key={option._id} 
            value={option.categories}
           >
          {option.categories}
          </option>
        ))}
       </select>
      </>
    )
}

export default Categories
```

Comment: Please don't use `console.log` output. Post something that is actually *copyable/usable*.

Comment: @ Yoshi thanks for pointing out. I updated the question

Comment: Thanks for your update, but how is an image any more *copyable/usable* than the console.log output from before? If you want people to help you, make it easy for them to help you. No one wants to type that example data just to get a prototype running.

Comment: Hey @ Yoshi I'm trying to be  precise, but yeah,  you right. So, can you help me with that, please? What is missing here to be more precise and make easier for community to help?

Comment: A good read in general is [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then for your question here, post the data shown in that image as JSON or a valid javascript data structure. This way people can copy.

Comment: Hey @ Yoshi this is the json data I get from server.  What else can I provide to clarify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224834/discussion-between-yoshi-and-greg).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to populate select dropdown elements with data from API - ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202344/how-to-populate-select-dropdown-elements-with-data-from-api-reactjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

```js
// Categories Component
const Categories = ({ data }) => {
  // You need an initial value if you like to show something when page first load
  // assuming you know exactly how your data will look like
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(data[0].categories[0]);
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = React.useState(data);
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Filter out categories by selected option
    const category = data.filter((item) => item.categories[0] === selected);

    setSelectedCategory(category);
    // Will change when data changes or another item selected
  }, [data, selected]);
  
  // Set selected option
  const handleSelcet = (e) => {
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  };
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <select onChange={handleSelcet}>
        {data.map((item) =>
          item.categories.map((category) => (
            <option key={category} value={category}>
              {category}
            </option>
          ))
        )}
      </select>
      {selectedCategory.map((category) => {
        return (
          <div key={category._id}>
            <p>Name: {category.name}</p>
            <p>Description: {category.description}</p>
            <p>Price: {category.price}</p>
            variants:
            <ul>
              {category.variants.map((item) => (
                <li key={item}>{item}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
            <img src={category.img} alt="" />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

// Data from API
const data = [
  {
    categories: ["women"],
    variants: ["white", "black", "green"],
    sizes: [38, 39, 40],
    _id: "5f8edf08880a821cb8757d8a",
    name: "Nike Air",
    description: "Tennis court levitating sneaker",
    img: "https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/PGTO_A0eLt4",
    price: 100
  },
  {
    categories: ["man"],
    variants: ["black", "green", "yellow"],
    sizes: [37, 39, 40, 42],
    _id: "5f8edf08880a821cb8757d9b",
    name: "Another Nike Air",
    description: "Another description",
    img: "https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900",
    price: 120
  }
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Categories data={data} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is an example with TypeScript

[image: Edit laughing-hawking-q9ut6]

Comment: thanks for answer and you effort. I tried to run the code you provided in codesandbox.  But have an error in first useState . it says 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined
' . I think if we solve this, app will run. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you use another sandbox or the one that linked [above](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-hawking-q9ut6)? Based on your code i assumed you're using TypeScript which already defines the data array. Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-test-4hkvr) without TypeScript, I just hardcoded the initial state.

Comment: looks great. I checked the link with typescript. I could solve the error putting initial value in quotes. But my problem is, that the 'data' props is the main data that I am already listing in 'ui', and want to output only the data from  'ui' based on selection. So we don't need to output anything, we have to show already created and styled data based on the category that will be selected.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that quite right. Do you mean you don't need any data to be shown initially and show it just on select? if so, just remove the `selected` state and move the `useEffet` logic to `handleSelcet` function. check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-test-forked-e2rl8)

Comment: sorry for being not precise. I've already listed data in 'ui' and initially I want to keep all data listed in 'ui', and, based on option selection,  show only the products which match the category.