# Cannot populate select list from Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, spring-boot, select

I am new in frontend application development and trying to populate a Select list from database, but cannot set `options` using the following approach using similar ones to **[How to populate select dropdown elements with data from API - ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202344/how-to-populate-select-dropdown-elements-with-data-from-api-reactjs)**

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const results = []

      // Fetch data
      GetWithAuth("/categories")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(value  => { 
        value.map(element => {
        // --> the value has data and push them to results variable
          results.push({
            key: element.name,
            value: element.id,
          });
        });
      })

      // --> options cannot be filled with results and just have the following value
      setOptions([
        {key: 'Select a category', value: ''},
        ...results
      ])
    }

    // Trigger the fetch
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Here is the service method that returns `Promise`:

```
export const GetWithAuth = (url) => {
  var request = fetch("/api" + url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: localStorage.getItem("tokenKey"),
    },
  });
  return request;
};
```

So, how should I populate my select list from database? What is the problem with the code above?

Comment: Does anybody else have never filled Select list from database in JavScript or React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your state inside "then" function, also instead of using map function, you should use forEach (because you are not using return keyword), but if you want to use map function, then you can use it this way

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {

      // Fetch data
      GetWithAuth("/categories")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(value  => { 
        const results = value.map(element => {
        // --> the value has data and push them to results variable
          return {
            key: element.name,
            value: element.id,
          }
        });

      setOptions([
        {key: 'Select a category', value: ''},
        ...results,
      ])
      })

    }

    // Trigger the fetch
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

But if you want to use forEach function, then you can do it this way

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {

      // Fetch data
      GetWithAuth("/categories")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(value  => { 
        const results = [];
        value.forEach(element => {
        // --> the value has data and push them to results variable
          results.push({
            key: element.name,
            value: element.id,
          })
        });

      setOptions([
        {key: 'Select a category', value: ''},
        ...results,
      ])
      })
    }

    // Trigger the fetch
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I had also tried forEach, but neither my usage nor your answer (gives *Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: value.forEach is not a function* error)  works :( This approach my be wrong, if you have any experience, you could suggest your approach. I don't have to use the approach above

Comment: Then try after adding a check before loop. like if "value" is not null or undefined and value is also an array. You can check this by console.log